# Table out of function

Tags: matrix

I want to create a table 4x4 that uses values n=1,2,3 and 4 and ksi=100, 250,600 and 950, out of this function:

```
FindRoot[SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi], {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}]
```

How could we do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[
    {n, ksi,
     c /. FindRoot[
       SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi],
       {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}]},
    {n, 4}, {ksi, {100, 250, 600, 950}}] //
   Flatten[#, 1] & //
  Prepend[(Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
     {"n", "ksi", "c"})] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! It works!

Answer (score 1):

```
t = Table[{n, ksi, 
   c /. FindRoot[
     SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi], {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}]}, {n, 
   1, 4}, {ksi, {100, 250, 600, 950}}];

t[[;; , ;; , 3]] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {Range@4, {100, 250, 600, 950}}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Table[FindRoot[SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi], {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}]
 , {n, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {ksi, {100, 250, 600, 950}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple:

```
Table[FindRoot[SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi], {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}],
{n, 1, 4}, {ksi, {100, 250, 600, 950}}]
```